# F# a function to check if a list is sorted or not

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I have to write a function, that returns true if a given list is sorted in ascending order. The empty and 1-element lists are sorted. Also, [5,12,12] should return true.

I've written a function that seems to work:

```
let rec isSorted (l: int list) = 
    match l with
    | [] -> true
    | [x] -> true
    | [x;y] -> x <= y
    | x::y::xr -> if x > y then false else isSorted([y] @ xr);
```

But it seems a bit off... I'm thinking there must be an easier way to do this? I hate that I have to match 4 cases, but I cant figure out how to make it any smarter.

Any better solutions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, never say

```
[y] @ xr
```

when

```
y :: xr
```

will do just as well.  (In general, `@` is a code smell.)

Kinda nitpicky, but the last line could be

```
| x::((y::_)as t) -> if x > y then false else isSorted(t)
```

and save you from doing any allocation.

Now, do you need the third case?  What happens if you remove it?

Comment: Thanks for this! By using y :: xr, the 3rd case was not needed. I guess this was what tricked me - it did look weird.

Answer (score 16):

you can combine existing functions:

```
let isAscending l = l |> Seq.pairwise |> Seq.forall (fun (a, b) -> a <= b)

printfn "%b" (isAscending []) // true
printfn "%b" (isAscending [1]) // true
printfn "%b" (isAscending [5;12]) // true
printfn "%b" (isAscending [5;12;12]) // true
printfn "%b" (isAscending [5;12;12;11]) // false
```

Comment: Ah, I don't know how much efficient with respect to the original solution, but elegant indeed :-)

Comment: @Edgar Sánchez: `Seq`s are lazily constructed/evaluated, so there is still just one traversal.

Answer (score 6):

Getting back to the original code (as opposed to the suggested library calls), I'd say you can make a few improvements:

- The third match case isn't really needed (was already mentioned).
- In the second case you don't want to give the value a name, you're not accessing it.
- In the forth case, it doesn't look right to take apart `y::xr` just to stitch it together again with `[y] @ xr` (or `y::xr`). An `as` expression seems nicer.
- You are just combining two logical results, the `if..then` looks a bit out of place.

I have come up with the following revised version:

```
let rec isSorted l =
    match l with
    | [] | [_] -> true
    | h1::(h2::_ as tail) -> h1 <= h2 && isSorted tail
```

I doubt it's more efficient than the original, but it's easier on the eye.

Comment: Nice work. I hope the OP returns to mark this as the accepted answer. I expect that it is much more efficient than the original, because you've saved the unnecessary and expensive reconstruction of the tail on each call "isSorted([y] @ xr)", although if that is fixed, as per Brian's post, then there probably isn't much of a saving, but, yes it is much easier on the eye.

Answer (score 2):

This is a particularly bad solution in terms of efficiency, so I'd never use this in the real world, but here is a nifty functional way of looking at the problem that I came up with as part of a blog example:

let isSorted l = l = (l|>List.sort)